# The given functions $y_1, y_2$ satisfy the corresponding homogeneous equation; find a particular solution of the given non-homogeneous equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given functions $y_1, y_2$ satisfy the corresponding homogeneous equation; find a particular solution of the given non-homogeneous equation.

$$(1-t)y''+ty'-y=2(t-1)^2 e^{(-t)}, 0<t<1 \\  y_1=e^t , y_2=t$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvAc1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$$(1-t)y''+ty'-y=2(t-1)^2 e^{-t}$$
$$\dfrac {-(t-1)y''+y'+(t-1)y'-y}{(t-1)^2}= 2e^{-t}$$
Integrate:
$$\dfrac {-y'}{(t-1)}+\dfrac {y}{(t-1)}= -2e^{-t}-C_1$$
$$y'-y= 2e^{-t}(t-1)+C_1(t-1)$$
$$(ye^{-t})'= 2e^{-2t}(t-1)+C_1(t-1)e^{-t}$$
Integrate again:
$$ye^{-t}= \frac 12e^{-2t}(1-2t)-C_1te^{-t}+C_2$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {y(t)= \frac 12e^{-t}(1-2t)+Ct+C_2e^{t}}$$